# Loading large images faster in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

Is there an accepted way, or updated way, to more quickly load images into a UIImageView?

My scenario: A collection view, with a large UIImageView. Only 1 cell is displayed at a time. I have implemented NSCache and Prefetching on the collection view already. Performance on scrolling has a pause partway through. The images I am using are "relatively" large, in order to accomodate both an iPad and iPhone layout. For example, images are 1600x1600px, RGB, PNG. (from 2-5MB compressed, ~10MB uncompressed, stored locally in the app)

Once the images are loaded, scrolling back and forth is usually OK then, ~60fps visually. But on **first load** they are ALWAYS jittery. BUT if I make the images physically smaller, such as 800x800 then they load quickly and I can not see a jitter on scroll. So I am dealing with an image size vs drawing speed issue. Same issue seen on a 5s as on an iPhone X.

The same performance hit happens with `[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]` or `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]`

I am reading how UIImages are decompressed before actually being drawn, and if the system has to draw a subsampled image, it can significantly affect main thread performance. I've done a little Instruments testing and confirmed that it appear that none of my code is actually slow, the image drawing of a PNG is slow.

Is there a newer way to do something similar to the content in links below, IE **draw an image in a CGContext and hope it stays cached**?

https://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/10/avoiding-image-decompression-sickness/

```
- (void)decompressImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1, 1));
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

https://gist.github.com/steipete/1144242

this seems like real overkill for me:
https://github.com/path/FastImageCache

Comment: This issue rendered closed or moot by changing large PNG images to JPG; loading is fast/fine with no other code changes.

Answer (score 5):

> I have implemented NSCache and Prefetching on the collection view already.

Good, but

- (1) you should not NSCache images
- (2) you should downsize the image to the max size needed for *display*
- (3) you should not be doing anything time-consuming in `itemForRowAt:` (you didn't show yours) — you have only a couple of milliseconds to produce the cell and get out
- (4) if you can't provide the image in time, provide a placeholder and get out of `itemForRowAt:`; you can always reload later when you have the real image
- (5) do all time-consuming work *off the main thread* (includes converting to UIImage and drawing UIImage to downsize it)
- (6) measure measure measure! this is why we have Instruments; do not *guess* where the problem is

Comment: All of this has been _heavily_ discussed on Stack Overflow as well as numerous WWDC videos etc. There is very clear prior art; you should use it.

Comment: I should also mention there's a major bug in prefetching: it can be happening exactly while you are trying to prepare the first cell, which slows you down. That bug is fixed in iOS 12. Again, there's a very good WWDC video on this.

Comment: Curious why to not use an image cache? Saves reloading from disk. BTW, [UIImage imageNamed:img] doesn't release memory after the ViewController is dismissed, so I am using imageWithContentsOfFile and I don't want to reload from disk all the time.

Comment: Apple has always been very clear about this. See for example WWDC 2011 video 318 minute 24. A UIImage that has been displayed consists of the entire decoded bitmap; that's _huge_. Again, use Instruments (Allocations) to see the effect of what you're doing. As I've said, you should watch the relevant WWDC videos (with Performance or Memory in their names, and also Image Best Practices and similar) for as far back as you can.

Comment: Having hard time finding that video online.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too. That's why I suggested looking over what you _can_ find.

Comment: Anyway it seems to me that in your situation the caching provided by `imageNamed` is exactly what you _do_ want. It seems silly to throw it away and cache it yourself, because you'll never do as good a job of it as the runtime would do for you.

Comment: No, it's not. I've seen the app memory increase by 200mb (after loading several cells) and never go down after the view controller for this collectionView is dismissed, and that's a different problem. Using imageWithContentsOfFile, the memory does return to its previous state when the viewController is dismissed. This is old but relevant to that problem, but not my original problem: http://www.alexcurylo.com/2009/01/13/imagenamed-is-evil/

Comment: Claims that `imageNamed:` caching doesn't work correctly are outdated and/or wrong. Measure measure measure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176818/discussion-between-chris-paveglio-and-matt).

Comment: A session from this year's WWDC covered image downsampling. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/219/